# Hierarchical Chart in Kendo

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am creating a project using javascript with kendo. In my project there is a requirement to implement hierarchical chart. I research this type of chart in kendo and could not get the exact result. Here is the demo code:

```js
function localDataSource(options) {
  var id = options.schema.model.id;
  var data = options.data;
  var newId = -1;
  var created, updated, deleted;

  var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource($.extend(true, {
    transport: {
      read: function(e) {
        created = {};
        updated = {};
        deleted = {};

        e.success(data || []);
      },

      update: function(e) {
        var item = e.data;
        if (!created[item[id]]) {
          updated[item[id]] = item;
        }
        e.success();
      },

      destroy: function(e) {
        var idValue = e.data[id];
        if (!created[idValue]) {
          deleted[idValue] = e.data;
        } else {
          delete created[idValue];
        }
        e.success();
      },
      create: function(e) {
        var item = e.data;
        item[id] = newId--;
        created[item[id]] = $.extend(true, {}, item);

        e.success(item);
      }
    },
  }, options));

  dataSource.getChanges = function() {
    return {
      deleted: toArray(deleted),
      created: toArray(created),
      updated: toArray(updated)
    }
  };

  return dataSource;
}

function toArray(changes) {
  var result = [];
  for (var id in changes) {
    result.push(changes[id]);
  }
  return result;
}

function createDiagram() {
  var shapesDataSource = localDataSource({
    data: [{
      "Id": 1,
      "JobTitle": "President"
    }, {
      "Id": 2,
      "JobTitle": "VP Finance",
      "Color": "#3399cc"
    }, {
      "Id": 3,
      "JobTitle": "VP Customer Relations",
      "Color": "#3399cc"
    }, {
      "Id": 4,
      "JobTitle": "VP Human Resources",
      "Color": "#3399cc"
    }],
    schema: {
      model: {
        id: "Id",
        fields: {
          Id: {
            type: "number",
            editable: false
          },
          JobTitle: {
            type: "string"
          },
          Color: {
            type: "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

  var connectionsDataSource = localDataSource({
    data: [{
      "Id": 1,
      "FromShapeId": 1,
      "ToShapeId": 2
    }, {
      "Id": 2,
      "FromShapeId": 1,
      "ToShapeId": 3
    }, {
      "Id": 3,
      "FromShapeId": 1,
      "ToShapeId": 4
    }],
    schema: {
      model: {
        id: "Id",
        fields: {
          Id: {
            type: "number",
            editable: false
          },
          from: {
            from: "FromShapeId",
            type: "number"
          },
          to: {
            from: "ToShapeId",
            type: "number"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

  var changesViewModel = kendo.observable({
    showChanges: function() {
      var diagram = $("#diagram").data("kendoDiagram");
      this.set("shapes", diagram.dataSource.getChanges());
      this.set("connections", diagram.connectionsDataSource.getChanges());
      this.set("visible", true);
    },
    shapes: {
      deleted: [],
      created: [],
      updated: []
    },
    connections: {
      deleted: [],
      created: [],
      updated: []
    }
  });

  kendo.bind($("#changes"), changesViewModel);

  $("#diagram").kendoDiagram({
    dataSource: shapesDataSource,
    connectionsDataSource: connectionsDataSource,
    layout: {
      type: "tree",
      subtype: "tipover",
      underneathHorizontalOffset: 140
    },
    shapeDefaults: {
      visual: visualTemplate,
      content: {
        template: "#= dataItem.JobTitle #",
        fontSize: 17
      }
    },
    connectionDefaults: {
      stroke: {
        color: "#586477",
        width: 2
      }
    },
    dataBound: onDataBound
  });
}

$(document).ready(createDiagram);

function visualTemplate(options) {
  var dataviz = kendo.dataviz;
  var g = new dataviz.diagram.Group();
  var dataItem = options.dataItem;

  if (dataItem.JobTitle === "President") {
    g.append(new dataviz.diagram.Circle({
      radius: 60,
      stroke: {
        width: 2,
        color: dataItem.Color || "#586477"
      },
      fill: "#e8eff7"
    }));
  } else {
    g.append(new dataviz.diagram.Rectangle({
      width: 240,
      height: 67,
      stroke: {
        width: 0
      },
      fill: "#e8eff7"
    }));

    g.append(new dataviz.diagram.Rectangle({
      width: 8,
      height: 67,
      fill: dataItem.Color,
      stroke: {
        width: 0
      }
    }));
  }

  return g;
}

function onDataBound(e) {
  this.bringIntoView(this.shapes);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" />

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="diagram"></div>
  <div id="changes">
    <button type="button" class="k-button" data-bind="click:showChanges">Show changes</button>
    <div data-bind="visible:visible">
      Deleted Shapes:
      <div data-bind="source: shapes.deleted" data-template="shapeItemTemplate">
      </div>
      <hr /> Created Shapes:
      <div data-bind="source: shapes.created" data-template="shapeItemTemplate">
      </div>
      <hr /> Updated Shapes:
      <div data-bind="source: shapes.updated" data-template="shapeItemTemplate">
      </div>
      <hr /> Deleted Connections:
      <div data-bind="source: connections.deleted" data-template="connectionItemTemplate">
      </div>
      <hr /> Created Connections:
      <div data-bind="source: connections.created" data-template="connectionItemTemplate">
      </div>
      <hr /> Updated Connections:
      <div data-bind="source: connections.updated" data-template="connectionItemTemplate">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/kendo" id="shapeItemTemplate">
    <div>
      JodTitle: #:JobTitle#
    </div>
  </script>

  <script type="text/kendo" id="connectionItemTemplate">
    <div>
      #console.log(data)# #:FromShapeId# - #:ToShapeId#
    </div>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But i need below type of graph with clickable circle.
[image]

Please help me to fix this problem

Comment: We do use kendo in your app too, but for a graph like that, we choose to use [mxgraph](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph). Much better than kendo, but a little complicated to use.